# Which Maven artifacts should I use to import PowerMock?

Tags: java, maven, mockito, powermock

What jars do I need to add to my `pom.xml` to get PowerMock working with Mockito? I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

but when I add the `@PrepareForTest` annotation at class level, Eclipse cannot find it, but it can find `PowerMockito`. What jar am I missing?

Comment: this is indeed a great question because, for a person whose using powermock for the first time, the jars though conveniently separated is not easy to just add onto using maven. I have to know which jar to begin with !

Answer (score 38):

According to the [Mockito 2 Maven](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven) page on the PowerMock wiki, use this:

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>2.0.9</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Be sure to check [the latest version number from GitHub's releases tab](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/releases) and check the [Maven section of the Getting Started wiki page](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Getting-Started#maven-setup) if you need EasyMock, TestNG, or Mockito 1.x (with a 1.x version of PowerMock).

`powermock-api-support` seems to be "[utility classes only](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-support)", where you still need the core libraries provided in `powermock-module-junit4`.

Comment: I've added the powermock-module-juint4 jar to the classpath but still seeing the same issue: >>> Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
  EnumHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration
 - PrepareForTest cannot be resolved to a type
 - The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type 
  PrepareForTest

Comment: Jeff's answer is correct; can you post the specific code throwing the exception?

Comment: Are you sure that no other dependencies are needed? There is no code throwing exceptions. When I add `@PrepareForTest` to my test class, Eclipse complains that it can't find `@PrepareForTest`. I have looked through the source of `powermock-module-junit4` and `powermock-api-mockito` and I cannot see the `@PrepareForTest` annotation. Can you tell me what jar contains @PrepareForTest in version 1.4.11?

Comment: @user [`powermock-core` contains `@PrepareForTest`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.java). However, since you can chase the same transitive dependencies from `powermock-api-mockito` in your question, it looks like maybe you set up Eclipse in such a way that transitive Maven dependencies aren't being pulled in. We'd need to know a little more about your Eclipse setup before figuring out that part, though.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I have a medium sized project using 50+ other referenced libraries, with no dependency issues. Strange that PowerMock is behaving differently.

Comment: Jeff's answer is still correct based on the information we have. Were you ever able to get past this issue?

Comment: Can you please explain why you reject my edit? I update version to the newest and also correct link to documentation... If you don't like other changes, please enter at least these two...

Comment: @Line Those two were fine, but the text edits were too far for me--punctuation was incorrect and TestNG details made the answer harder to follow--and I had no "improve" or "partially accept" buttton, just "reject". Though your edit had other approvers, there was at least one other reviewer who rejected for the same reason, and your edit log likely shows that full text reason. [Please be mindful when your edits change a post's meaning.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/201031)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Pity that you didn't have this button. Author didn't mention jUnit, so your answer may be applicable (and in fact it was), but didn't had to...
Besides - "You edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning." - I don't feel like change the meaning. But ok, I respect your opinion.

Comment: @Line I appreciate your understanding--even when not disagreeing with my answer, your change _broadens_ it in a way I wasn't wholly comfortable with (as you had it). Edits are held to a high standard on SO/SE, in part because the original author's name stays on it, so you're speaking for me here. A comment--or separate answer--may be a good way to proceed in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have this import:

```
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
```

This jar has it:

- [powermock-mockito-1.5.1-full.jar](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/list)

Answer (score 1):

You are writting:

```
    @PrepareForTest(Class.class);
```

Instead of:

```
    @PrepareForTest(Class.class)
```

I had exactly the same issue and solved it that way.

Comment: A good IDE would yell at you for this syntax mistake. If you add a semi-colon(;) after the annotation Eclipse complains `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration`
@l3k

Answer (score 0):

Download the Mockito dependency zip file apart from your **powermock-module-junit4** & **powermock-api-mockito dependecies**. Add that jars directly in your project it should work and configure your pom accordingly.

[Power Mockito dependencies - All Jars](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Getting-Started#mockito)