# PowerMock not finding PrepareForTest annotation

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I am writing test cases for Java classes, and I am using the PowerMock framework for the first time. The dependencies I added to my pom.xml are shown below, along with the full error message. When I tried using the `@PrepareForTest` annotation in my test class, it did not import anhything. I checked inside the `powermock-core` JAR and I didn't find anything corresponding to 
`import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;`.

I followed [Which Maven artifacts should I use to import PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645465/which-maven-artifacts-should-i-use-to-import-powermock), but it didn't work.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerFactory.createMockHa‌ndler(Lorg/mockito/m‌​ock/MockCreationSett‌​ings;)Lorg/mockito/i‌​nternal/InternalMock‌​Handler; at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockC‌reator.createMethodI‌​nvocationControl(Def‌​aultMockCreator.java‌​:114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it's works for me.
Did you try to build an app?

```
mvn clean install
```

And you should check if you are importing the test:

```
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
```

For your second error:
You should use powermock version 1.7.1 with junit 4.4 or above.

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes it worked after deleting from local repository and rebuild the project.

Comment: Now I am facing below issue

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerFactory.createMockHandler(Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;)Lorg/mockito/internal/InternalMockHandler;
 at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:114)

Comment: please share your mail id

Comment: HI rodgenk,please find the attached files i send to you from arunsphassan@gmail.com

Comment: You are truing to use mockito 1.10.19, this version doesn't have method https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/internal/handler/MockHandlerFactory.html MockHandlerFactory.createMockHandler(settings);

Comment: which version of mockito to use to resolve and make my testcase work for powermock

Comment: I have done, please see the post, you should use powermock 1.7.1.